# When I add of {Overflow-X:hidden;} to html/body it causes divs to vertical scroll within parent div, what have I done wrong?

Tags: css, overflow

Whilst trying to make it so that on mobile browsers there is no horizontal scroll, only vertical, I have run into an overflow issue:

***The addition of overflow-x:hidden to html, body or a div wrapping content is causing certain divs to now vertically scroll within their parent divs***

A working codepen example is [here](https://codepen.io/matbowden/pen/1e0d5899d628934ab3c01040ff7e30a4)

You can toggle the overflow on and off and notice the difference in vertical scroll, in particular when hovering over the title creds.

For simplicity, below is the basic build structure:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav-bar"></div>
        <div class="100vhlogo"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-section-1"></div>
            <div class="content-section-2"></div>
            <div class="content-section-3"></div>
            <div class="content-section-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When overflow:hidden is not applied, the site scrolls perfectly vertically.

Apply overlfow-x:hidden and when trying to scroll, "content-section-1" scrolls within the div "content" rather than pushing the whole page up.

However, oddly... "content-section-2" allows for normal scrolling, but reach the footer and "content-section-4" behaves oddly too.

I have tried placing the setting at different points (on html, on html & body, on a div wrapper...) I have tried removing the actual overflow by ensuring divs are not oversized and yet the issue still persists.

Comment: html{
  overflow-x:hidden 
}  usualy works for me, when only applying to body doesn't work

Comment: I already have that in place, the problem is the effect it causes, meaning certain divs now scroll vertically within one another.

Comment: I initially thought it was to do with the first div being 100%vh - but even with removal of this, I still get scroll issues with content sections scrolling inside their containing div.